# Xcode - how to disable Remote notification sound by code when the application in background

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

i know we could disable Notification sound from the "Notification Center" of the device,
does anybody know how to disable Remote notification sound using Xcode for notifications received when the application is in background?
i've tried to call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

but it only remove the option to disable the Sound from "Notification Center" but the notification still play sound

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't include `sound` in the notification payload.
2. Don't register for sound notification type. Don't include `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` in:

   ```
   [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
   ```